# Control Travel Speed of IOS Locations Simulator

Tags: ios, gps, ios-simulator, core-location

Is there a way to control the travel speed in the IOS Simulator?

I have given the simulator a GPX file with a a series of  way points. I can click off the simulator. I then get my updates.

However, I'd like to travel the route in an SR-71 rather than a C-152.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to write a software that creates a gpx file with  waypoints with correct timestamp, speed, and inter point distance related to a specified speed.
An input file where some waypoints are defined define the route. The inbetween points you have to interpolate with correct time, speed attributes